# How to generate non-repeating numbers in C?

Tags: arrays, c, random, passwords

my first post here.

I'm trying to write a program in C, which generates a random password made of numbers, letters and capitals. The problem is that characters in password must NOT be repeated. I tried a few ways to prevent that, but nothing seemed to work.

```
void createPassword() {
char password[LENGTH];
char nums[] = "0123456789";
char letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char caps[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int selector = rand() % 3; //random choice of character type
int i;

printf("Vytvorene heslo: ");
for(i = 0;i < LENGTH;i++) {
    if(selector == 1) { //if selector == 1, add number to password etc.
        password[i] = nums[rand() % 10];
        printf("%c", password[i]);
        selector = rand() % 3;
    }
    else if(selector == 2) {
        password[i] = letters[rand() % 26];
        printf("%c", password[i]);
        selector = rand() % 3;
    }
    else { 
        password[i] = caps[rand() % 26];
        printf("%c", password[i]);
        selector = rand() % 3;
    }
}}
```

I'll be glad if someone could tell me what to do next.

Comment: And understand that by artificially restricting a random-draw to any specific subset of an alphabet, you're actually making your security *worse*, not better.

Comment: Note: I'd start by puitting `int selector = rand() % 3;` **inside the loop** (and, before assigning you could test if the character is already present, and try again)

Comment: *The problem is that characters in password must NOT be repeated*  That means it's ***NOT*** random.

Comment: "The problem is that characters in password must NOT be repeated." As an observation that means the password is not truly random, although technically rand() in not truly random anyway. But  of course this in just an observation, not a criticism of your approach to passwords.

Comment: to all responders: using `srand()` will likely result in a **very  insecure** passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking a random index of an array is the same as picking the values of a shuffled array sequentially. I used **[Fisher–Yates shuffle Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-a-given-array-using-fisher-yates-shuffle-algorithm/)** for shuffling of the array. After generating a shuffled array, just pick the index of the next character from the shuffled array, and use `symbols[]` to access the corresponding character from it. Also. I used `srand(time(0))` to give a random seed for the random number generator. Include `time.h` for using `time(0)`.

```
void createPassword() {
    char password[LENGTH];
    int total = 10+26+26;
    char symbols[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int i;
    int ar[total];
    for(i = 0; i < total; i++){
        ar[i] = i;
    }
    srand(time(0));
    for (i = total-1; i >= 1; i--){

        // get random 0 <= temp <= i
        int temp = rand() % (i+1);
        
        // Swap ar[temp] and ar[i]
        int temp2 = ar[i];
        ar[i] = ar[temp];
        ar[temp] = temp2;
    }
    printf("Vytvorene heslo: ");
    for(i = 0;i < LENGTH;i++) {
        password[i] = symbols[ar[i]];
        printf("%c", password[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: consider `total` -> `sizeof(symbols) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

That's not a big deal, random seeds are similar for several runs in C.

You may need to set the random seed to `time(0)` by adding something like this, first of your code:

```
srand(time(0));
```

You should import `time.h` too.

```
#include <time.h>
```

Besides if you want to make a password consisting numbers and alphabets at the same time you may need to move `selector` assignment into the loop.

Comment: @vacexpfleger correct; that is where it belongs; not in the generator function as the accepted answer suggests. `srand` should never be in a potentially repeatable code path unless the specific reason for repeating a pseudorandom sequence is the goal (i..e hard-seeding with intent). In short you're (already) doing it right, and the accepted answer shouldn't have it, but I assume you already knew that.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to force random numbers with no repeating letters can be implemented by using an array of elements, that will play the role of a card deck.

Each time you get a card, you get it from the rest of the deck (there's a point that differentiates cards that have been already xtracted with cards that are still to be output)  You select a random number between 0 to n-1 where n-1 is the number of cards left in the deck.  Once extracted, you switch the card extracted with the first of the group that is still to be extracted, and advance the point one position behind it, so it becomes already extracted and is not selected again.

A sample implementation is shown below, in the function `extract`, which uses an array of `cell`s to store the available objects to print (they can be anything, they are `char` in the given implementation to be able to produce what you want ---random strings with non repeating characters):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

typedef char cell;

/* cell is a type (the above definition allows to be generic)
 * array is the array of cards still to be output, n is its size.
 * which is the card we select from the array, so it must be in
 * range 0..n-1. */
cell extract(cell *array, size_t n, int which)
{
    if (which) {
        /* exchange position n with position 0 */
        cell temp = array[0];
        array[0] = array[which];
        array[which] = temp;
    }
    return array[0];
}

/* this is a simple main program to illustrate how to use the
 * function above. */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned N = 10;
    unsigned seed = 0;
    /* we use an array, because we need to modify it. */
    char alpha[1024] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int opt;
    int show_seed = 0;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:s:a:S")) != EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'n': N = atoi(optarg); break;
        case 's': seed = atoi(optarg); break;
        case 'S': show_seed = 1; break;
        case 'a': strncpy(alpha, optarg, sizeof alpha); break;
        }
    }

    if (seed) srand(seed);
    else {
        sranddev();
        srand(seed = (unsigned)rand());
        if (show_seed) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "seed = %u\n",
                    seed);
        }
    }

    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    int len;
    cell *pos;
    for (pos = alpha, len = strlen(alpha);
        *pos && len && N--;
        pos++, len--)
    {
        putchar(extract(pos, len, rand() % len));
    }
    puts(""); /* final \n */
}
```

The program's usage is:

```
deck [ -a string  ][ -S ][ -s seed ][ -n N ]
where:
  -a allows you to specify the string where characters will be taken from.  Defaults to ABCDEF...XYZ
  -S prints the seed used in the run, so you can specify it to initialize the random number generator.
  -s specifies a seed from a previous run to generate the same sequence.  Defaults to a random initialization based on sranddev() (FreeBSD)
  -n specifies the number of characters to select from the string.  Defaults to 10.
```

A sample run is:

```
$ deck -s 123456
UKWOACYZLI
$ deck -s 123456 -n 26
UKWOACYZLITPJHQESVGMRBXFDN
$ _
```

As you see no character is repeated.